# Dictionary in Function

Tags: python

```
def build_profile(first, last, **user_info):  

    profile = {}   
    profile['first_name'] = first 
    profile['last_name'] = last

    for key, value in user_info.items():
        profile[key] = value

    return profile

user_profile = build_profile('albert', 'einstein',
location='princeton',field='physics')
print(user_profile)
```

Hello guys! Just started studying python a week ago from the book "Python Crash Course", I have a little question about this program.

Why in the `build_profile` they write `location='princeton'` and not `'location' = 'princeton'`

Comment: Because that's how Python syntax works for keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is `location` and `field` both become part of `**kwargs` or, in this case `**user_info`. `kwargs` stands for `keyword arguments` and thus Python recognizes that the user can enter a number of keyword parameters, and will happily accept them.

What is happening at a deeper level is a dictionary is passed to build profile that looks something like this:

```
user_info = {'location':'princeton', 'field':'physics'}
```

This means that it is possible to pass a dictionary to any `**kwargs` argument. In the case of supplying keywords instead, Python will, in essence, build the dictionary automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not actually a dictionary that you are passing into your function, they are [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) which you can read about in the Python documentation linked.

Keyword arguments have a lot of uses which are too many to enumerate here.

In your function definition ** means (and some additional keyword arguments) which allows the user to provide any keyword arguments they want. Try adding `random_key="test"` for example

Answer (score 0):

you should read up on this question 
[Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) to understand what you are doing, but that **user_info is described as keyword argument (and is usually written as **kwargs). When calling that funciton, since it includes a **kwargs input, you can write in any additional fields you might want. Then, this function: 
`for key, value in user_info.items():
        profile[key] = value`

Creates those variables in the profile dict